# Regarding the notation in a curve integral

Tags: integration, notation

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $0 < \phi < \pi$ and consider the curve
>
> $$C_{\phi} := \bigg\{ (2+ \cos(t), 1+ \sin(t)) \ \bigg\lvert \  \lvert t \rvert \le \phi \bigg\}. $$
>
> Calculate the curve integral
> $$ \frac{1}{2} \int_{C_\phi} y \ dx - x \ dy. $$

I do not know what $y \ dx $ and $x \ dy $ should mean in this context. Could you please explain?

Comment: Are you taking vector calculus atm?

Comment: @I was suspended for talking:Yes

Comment: $x=2+\cos(t), y=1+\sin(t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parametrize the curve with functions $x=f(t)$, $y=g(t)$ over an interval $a \leq t \leq b$, then
$$
    \frac{1}{2} \int_{C_\phi} (y\,dx - x\,dy) = \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b \left(g(t)f'(t) -f(t)g'(t)\right)\,dt
$$
Formally, you take the functions defining the parametrization and substitute them into the integrand for $x$ and $y$.  Then you take the differentials of those functions and substitute them for $dx$ and $dy$.

Your curve $C_\phi$ is already described by a parametrization $x = 2+ \cos t,y=1 + \sin t$, $-\phi \leq t \leq \phi$.  Therefore $dx = - \sin t \,dt$ and $dy = \cos t\,dt$ and
$$
    \frac{1}{2} \int_{C_\phi} (y\,dx - x\,dy) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\phi}^\phi \left((1+\sin t)(-\sin t) -(2+\cos t)(\cos t)\right)\,dt
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: This suffices. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

hint: replace $dx$ with $\frac{dx}{dt}dt$ and likewise for the other term, and integrate w.r.t. $t$